# About BGV Scheme Batching Technique

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am reading [BGV12](https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/6892-Fall2013/BGV.pdf) about BGV homomorphic scheme right now.But I am being stuck to understand Batching technique in this paper.

In Pack function (page 32),this paper feeds ciphertext $c_i$ and sk $s_1$ into $\sigma_{1\rightarrow i}()$ function,so $s_1$ and $c_i$ must be in ideal $\mathfrak{p}_1$.But I cannot figure out why they are elements of ideal $\mathfrak{p}_1$.